# why permission of file created by open() is different with by touch?

Tags: c, linux

```
#include<apue.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int fd = open("test.txt",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC);
    int pid,status;
    const char *str_for_parent = "str_for_parent\n";
    const char *str_for_child = "str_for_child\n";
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        err_sys("fork error");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        write(fd,str_for_child,strlen(str_for_child)+1);
        _exit(0);
    }
    wait(&status);
    write(fd,str_for_parent,strlen(str_for_parent)+1);

    return 0;
}
```

The `test.txt` is created by open().But it's permission(`---------x`) is different with those files(`-rw-rw-r--`) created by `touch` or any other softwares in my system.my **umask** is `0002`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open` actually takes an (optional) third parameter:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

The mode of the new file is set to the AND of `mode` and the inverse of your `umask` (ie, `mode & ~umask`). Since you're not passing `mode`, it's getting initialized to some garbage, and you're getting the wrong mode as a result.

Generally if you're passing `O_CREAT`, you should pass a `mode` of `0666`, unless you have some specific reason to use some other mode (eg, if you want to make sure the file is not readable by other users regardless of what the umask is set to).

Answer (score 2):

If you supply the `O_CREAT` flag to `open()`, you must also supply a third `mode` parameter, which is combined with the current umask to set the created file's permission bits.

Unless you are specifically creating an executable file, you should almost always use `0666` as this parameter:

```
int fd = open("test.txt",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
```

This should give you the same result that you see from `touch`.  Note that the leading zero in C indicates an octal constant.